# Conditional Styling of the bootstrap button by adding a border

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

```
    <script src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
      href="bootstrap-select.css">

           <select ng-model="item" data-style="btn"  class="selectpicker" ng-style="valid  && {'btn-custom': 'border:1px solid green'}" ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in items">
             <option value="">Select Service</option>
    </select>
```

I am using 'bootstrap-select' to show a drop-down control. Since this is an AngularJS application I have a scope variable. This variable 'valid' is set to true. I am trying to add a red border to the bootstrap button displayed by bootstrap-select when this variable 'valid' is set to true.

But this style is not properly applied to the button.

I have looked at many advanced bootstrap button styles but they seem to be too advanced for this requirement. 
How can I do this ?

bootstrap-select displays this button and when I add style="border: 1px solid red;" in Chrome by editing this and saving I get a red border. But I am unsure about the code that can generate this.

```
   <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle selectpicker btn" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Select Service"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Select Service</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button>
```

I have a JFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/cjq7jgkn/6/) created by a AngularJS forum member based on my question that shows an example. But this is not exactly what I want. I have explained what I am looking for above.

Update : I am editing this because it is easier than adding comments.

The suggested new code is applied like this.

```
 <select ng-model="item" class="selectpicker ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-style="{ 'border' : true ? '1px solid red':'1px solid green'}" ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in items" style="border: 1px solid red; display: none;"><option value="" class="">Select Service</option><option value="0">Peter F. Hamilton</option><option value="1">Alastair Reynolds</option><option value="2">Isaac Asimov</option></select>
```

But if I can apply it on the button(by editing in chrome) it works. It looks like this code should be used in a way that adds the style attribute to the bootstrap button that bootstrap-select uses.

The line that displays the button is shown in the question.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle). Your `ng-style` results in a boolean value and not in an object.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your requirement correctly. You can use conditional styling in ng-style as:

```
ng-style="{ 'border' : valid ? '1px solid red':'1px solid green'}"
```

Here is [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjq7jgkn/7/)
Note that this requires AngularJS version with 1.1.5+

Comment: I have edited the original post. I started to use ng-style because bootstrap-select didn't apply the style in the proper place. There are a few layers sorrounding the button.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan, the usage of "ng-style" in your updated question is not the same as mine. Your usage is wrong, try as in my answer.

Comment: I am able to see the style attribute properly applied but on the wrong component. I couldn't understand why you think it is wrong.

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan, because you are not using variable named "valid" and you have hard coded the style="border: 1px solid red; display: none;".

Comment: Oh! It is a test. I was checking where it is applied. It appears that the bootstrap-select attribute data-style or something like that will help me apply the style on the inner button. If that happens the style is applied and the 'component's' border changes. Otherwise the border is hidden in a layer beneath.

Comment: <select ng-model="item" id="test"  class="selectpicker"  ng-options="item.code as item.name for item in items">
                 <option value="">Select Service</option>
        </select>                                                                                                 $("button[data-id='test']").css({ "border": "1px solid red"});                          This is what works here.  Generated data-id in the button has the same value as id in select.                                                              @Uluk I meant bootstrap-select